# Not enough storage is available with 64 bits system

Tags: mongodb

I run mongo server on a desktop with Windows 7, 64bits, 4Gb RAM, and virtual memory auto managed. After a while, trying to add another entry to my database, I got this error. I am now unable to run the mongo server anymore, unable to repair the database etc.

```
2014-05-12T15:11:03.711-0400 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile C:\mongodb\data\db\dbTestJig.8, filling with zeroes...
2014-05-12T15:11:06.628-0400 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile C:\mongodb\data\db\dbTestJig.8, size: 512MB, took 2.909 secs
2014-05-12T15:11:07.549-0400 [conn224] MapViewOfFileEx for C:\mongodb\data\db\dbTestJig.8 at address 00000000 failed with errno:8 Not enough storage is available to process this command. (file size is 536870912) in MemoryMappedFile::map
2014-05-12T15:11:07.985-0400 [conn224] dbTestJig.JigElements Fatal Assertion 16166
2014-05-12T15:11:38.640-0400 [conn224] mongod.exe ...\src\mongo\util\log.cpp(122) mongo::logContext+0xa7
2014-05-12T15:11:38.640-0400 [conn224] mongod.exe ...\src\mongo\util\assert_util.cpp(138) mongo::fassertFailed+0x92
2014-05-12T15:11:38.640-0400 [conn224] mongod.exe ...\src\mongo\util\mmap_win.cpp(211) mongo::MemoryMappedFile::map+0x6f9
2014-05-12T15:11:38.640-0400 [conn224] mongod.exe ...\src\mongo\db\storage\durable_mapped_file.cpp(151) mongo::DurableMappedFile::create+0xe5
2014-05-12T15:11:38.640-0400 [conn224] mongod.exe ...\src\mongo\db\storage\data_file.cpp(146) mongo::DataFile::open+0x14f
2014-05-12T15:11:38.640-0400 [conn224] mongod.exe ...\src\mongo\db\storage\extent_manager.cpp(161) mongo::ExtentManager::getFile+0x46a
2014-05-12T15:11:38.640-0400 [conn224] mongod.exe ...\src\mongo\db\storage\extent_manager.cpp(381) mongo::ExtentManager::createExtent+0xdc
2014-05-12T15:11:38.640-0400 [conn224] mongod.exe ...\src\mongo\db\storage\extent_manager.cpp(484) mongo::ExtentManager::increaseStorageSize+0x8b
2014-05-12T15:11:38.655-0400 [conn224] mongod.exe ...\src\mongo\db\structure\record_store.cpp(213) mongo::SimpleRecordStoreV1::allocRecord+0x12a
2014-05-12T15:11:38.655-0400 [conn224] mongod.exe ...\src\mongo\db\structure\record_store.cpp(95) mongo::RecordStoreV1Base::insertRecord+0x62
2014-05-12T15:11:38.655-0400 [conn224] mongod.exe ...\src\mongo\db\catalog\collection.cpp(233) mongo::Collection::_insertDocument+0x97
2014-05-12T15:11:38.655-0400 [conn224] mongod.exe ...\src\mongo\db\catalog\collection.cpp(190) mongo::Collection::insertDocument+0x1b4
2014-05-12T15:11:38.655-0400 [conn224] mongod.exe ...\src\mongo\db\commands\write_commands\batch_executor.cpp(1057) mongo::singleInsert+0x64
2014-05-12T15:11:38.655-0400 [conn224] mongod.exe ...\src\mongo\db\commands\write_commands\batch_executor.cpp(984) mongo::insertOne+0x14d
2014-05-12T15:11:38.655-0400 [conn224] mongod.exe ...\src\mongo\db\commands\write_commands\batch_executor.cpp(1019) mongo::WriteBatchExecutor::execOneInsert+0xa9
2014-05-12T15:11:38.655-0400 [conn224] mongod.exe ...\src\mongo\db\commands\write_commands\batch_executor.cpp(830) mongo::WriteBatchExecutor::execInserts+0x105
2014-05-12T15:11:38.655-0400 [conn224] mongod.exe ...\src\mongo\db\commands\write_commands\batch_executor.cpp(710) mongo::WriteBatchExecutor::bulkExecute+0x44
2014-05-12T15:11:38.655-0400 [conn224] mongod.exe ...\src\mongo\db\commands\write_commands\batch_executor.cpp(248) mongo::WriteBatchExecutor::executeBatch+0x4e7
2014-05-12T15:11:38.655-0400 [conn224] mongod.exe ...\src\mongo\db\commands\write_commands\write_commands.cpp(146) mongo::WriteCmd::run+0x1b8
2014-05-12T15:11:38.655-0400 [conn224] mongod.exe ...\src\mongo\db\dbcommands.cpp(1357) mongo::_execCommand+0x66
2014-05-12T15:11:38.655-0400 [conn224] dbTestJig.JigElements 
2014-05-12T15:11:38.655-0400 [conn224]
***aborting after fassert() failure
2014-05-12T15:11:39.607-0400 [conn224] mongod.exe ...\src\mongo\util\signal_handlers.cpp(107) mongo::`anonymous namespace'::abruptQuit+0xd1
2014-05-12T15:11:39.607-0400 [conn224] mongod.exe f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\winsig.c(586) raise+0x17a
2014-05-12T15:11:39.607-0400 [conn224] mongod.exe f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\abort.c(74) abort+0x10
2014-05-12T15:11:39.607-0400 [conn224] mongod.exe ...\src\mongo\util\assert_util.cpp(142) mongo::fassertFailed+0xfd
2014-05-12T15:11:39.607-0400 [conn224] mongod.exe ...\src\mongo\util\mmap_win.cpp(211) mongo::MemoryMappedFile::map+0x6f9
2014-05-12T15:11:39.607-0400 [conn224] mongod.exe ...\src\mongo\db\storage\durable_mapped_file.cpp(151) mongo::DurableMappedFile::create+0xe5
2014-05-12T15:11:39.607-0400 [conn224] mongod.exe ...\src\mongo\db\storage\data_file.cpp(146) mongo::DataFile::open+0x14f
2014-05-12T15:11:39.607-0400 [conn224] mongod.exe ...\src\mongo\db\storage\extent_manager.cpp(161) mongo::ExtentManager::getFile+0x46a
2014-05-12T15:11:39.607-0400 [conn224] mongod.exe ...\src\mongo\db\storage\extent_manager.cpp(381) mongo::ExtentManager::createExtent+0xdc
2014-05-12T15:11:39.607-0400 [conn224] mongod.exe ...\src\mongo\db\storage\extent_manager.cpp(484) mongo::ExtentManager::increaseStorageSize+0x8b
2014-05-12T15:11:39.607-0400 [conn224] mongod.exe ...\src\mongo\db\structure\record_store.cpp(213) mongo::SimpleRecordStoreV1::allocRecord+0x12a
2014-05-12T15:11:39.607-0400 [conn224] mongod.exe ...\src\mongo\db\structure\record_store.cpp(95) mongo::RecordStoreV1Base::insertRecord+0x62
2014-05-12T15:11:39.607-0400 [conn224] mongod.exe ...\src\mongo\db\catalog\collection.cpp(233) mongo::Collection::_insertDocument+0x97
2014-05-12T15:11:39.607-0400 [conn224] mongod.exe ...\src\mongo\db\catalog\collection.cpp(190) mongo::Collection::insertDocument+0x1b4
2014-05-12T15:11:39.607-0400 [conn224] mongod.exe ...\src\mongo\db\commands\write_commands\batch_executor.cpp(1057) mongo::singleInsert+0x64
2014-05-12T15:11:39.607-0400 [conn224] mongod.exe ...\src\mongo\db\commands\write_commands\batch_executor.cpp(984) mongo::insertOne+0x14d
2014-05-12T15:11:39.607-0400 [conn224] mongod.exe ...\src\mongo\db\commands\write_commands\batch_executor.cpp(1019) mongo::WriteBatchExecutor::execOneInsert+0xa9
2014-05-12T15:11:39.607-0400 [conn224] mongod.exe ...\src\mongo\db\commands\write_commands\batch_executor.cpp(830) mongo::WriteBatchExecutor::execInserts+0x105
2014-05-12T15:11:39.607-0400 [conn224] mongod.exe ...\src\mongo\db\commands\write_commands\batch_executor.cpp(710) mongo::WriteBatchExecutor::bulkExecute+0x44
2014-05-12T15:11:39.607-0400 [conn224] mongod.exe ...\src\mongo\db\commands\write_commands\batch_executor.cpp(248) mongo::WriteBatchExecutor::executeBatch+0x4e7
2014-05-12T15:11:39.607-0400 [conn224] SEVERE: Got signal: 22 (SIGABRT).
```

Comment: Make sure you have a page file configured that can grow to the recommended size. (It won't actually use the page file, it just needs to have it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of the MongoDB edition was the 32bits one.... Just change to the 64bits one and everything was fine.